# What should be used for sharing the volume of StatefulSet between its pods: NFS ou etcd?

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, etcd, statefulset

I want to deploy a high performance (multi node) database. To do that, StatefulSet will be used.
So, what should be used for sharing the content of the database between the pods of the StatefulSet application? `NFS` could do the work? or `etcd`?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

What database do you want to use? etcd will not fit definitely, because it is a key\value storage service. 
If you want to use something like mongoDB then NFS should fit. Also look at the list of persistant volume types - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes

Comment: This repo [mappedinn/kubernetes-wordpress-with-nfs-volume-on-gke](https://github.com/mappedinn/kubernetes-wordpress-with-nfs-volume-on-gke) is having a problem even it is using **nfs**. Strange no?

Comment: Could you be more specific? As I see the problem is not related  to the NFS but to the container: `Warning FailedSync Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "wordpress" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 2m40s restarting failed container=wordpress pod=wp01-wordpress-2362719074-bv53t_default(44ba1226-306d-11e7-a0d1-42010a8e0084)"` I had same issue with postgres statefull set on cinder volume.

Comment: How did you solved your problem with your postgres statefulset on cinder volume??

Comment: Just delete the pod and let kubernetes to recreate it. On my system this problem appears sometimes when docker container crashed or cinder is unavailable. To be honest I didn't investigate why it happens but it definitely not related to the NFS.